# What are the default repeater offsets on 70cm in different countries?

Tags: repeater, frequency

I am looking for a reference list of the default repeater offsets by frequency and country on the 70cm band, to supply it into a radio control software. Most radios come with a list built-in, but the respective data is hard to collect.

There is an [US repeater offset list](http://cs.yrex.com/ke3fl/htm/RepeaterOffsets.htm), that lists +-5MHz for the 440MHz range, but I know from Germany at least that +-7.6MHz are used.

I know that a repeater operator may divert from the defaults, but most are following them and it is sane to provide them as the default radio configuration.

**What repeater shifts are used by default on 70cm in different countries?**

**Update:** Please provide the start frequency, end frequency and according shift where possible.

Comment: If you end up collecting a list from various sources, could you maybe publish it on Github as a machine-readable file of some sort? YAML, XML, JSON, CSV, whatever, as long as it can be converted to other formats and code. I'm sure it'd be useful for others!

Comment: Sure, can do. What about "start-frequency, end-frequency, shift"?

Comment: I think an exhaustive list of the offsets everywhere in the world is too broad for a single question. The difficulty in obtaining such is probably why you are unable to find it: no one has been sufficiently compensated to do it.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @PhilFrost here - StackOverflow isn't really designed for acquiring exhaustive lists.

Comment: I had hoped that SO karma would provide some compensation for a possible author. Even though SO is not designed for acquiring lists (which is an SO issue), I hoped to get some answers together and maybe create one table that can be edited later on.

Answer (score 2):

In Argentina and the USA, the offset for 70cm repeaters is +- 5.0 MHz.

Answer (score 2):

In Slovenia (S5) the offset for 70cm repeaters is -7.6 MHz.